# Help with Pro Tools recording issues

Tags: audio-recording, pro-tools, troubleshooting

First off, I've looked through the Pro Tools help and such, and couldn't find an answer.

I'm trying to record my guitar in Pro Tools 9, through an MBox mini.  When I try to assign it to an audio track, none of the inputs work, but I can still hear the guitar.  If I use an instrument track, input 2 works, yet it won't record.

Comment: Did your question get answered?  If so, please select an answer by clicking the green check mark next to the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

The MBox mini seems to have a mix control knob. Try tweaking the position of the knob to see if the signal you're hearing is routed through the interface directly or if it is already routed through ProTools. If the knob is turned all the way to 'P/B' and you're no longer hearing the guitar, then your ProTools is not configured properly. Have you checked 'Setup' > 'I/O...' for a correct mapping of the inputs? If not create a new mono path and assign the desired input. Then assign the path to your mono audio track, enable track record on the particular track and try recording again. You should be able to hear your guitar as soon as you enable track recording.

Answer (score 2):

make sure your audio track's input is set to analogue 1&2,
that your track is set to record (obviously),
and also make sure you follow the steps that the previous commenter mentioned.

Don't use instrument tracks for audio either.
Those are meant for midi so that you don't have to bus your midi track to an audio track anymore and so it's all in one track instead of always having two for every part.

If that doesn't solve it,
it's definitely just something silly that you just missed.
That's how things go with pro tools sometimes.
I hope that helps.

Comment: oh, and your audio track's output should be set to analogue 1&2 as well.

Comment: I'd recommend editing any extra info like that into your answer. It helps make it a single authoritative source, especially if it's upvoted and accepted. The idea is to have a collection of the best questions and answers we can :)